# Should I remove the public key after adding it to the server's authorized_keys file?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, cryptography, openssh

I'm done setting up ssh login using public/private key pair. I have my `id_rsa` (private key) in my `~/.ssh` directory and also still have `id_rsa.pub` (public key) in the same directory. I'm no security expert, but something tells me its not a good idea to keep both keys in the same directory?

Is it a good practice to remove the public key file after I've added it to the server's `authorized_keys` file? If there is no harm in keeping the public key around, should I move it to a different directory?

One shortcoming I can think of is that I would have to re-generate a public/private key pair if I wanted to ssh into to a different server. Is it a good practice to generate a new public/private key pair for different servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "secret" part of your key needs to be kept safe - in your home directory is the usual place. The public key is MEANT to be shared, that's the whole point of it being public.

So, make sure your .ssh directory is kept safely protected at all times.

The public key isn't secret, so whilst you can delete it if you want, it won't help much, since anyone that can read authorized_keys can get it... It is there in full view.

Obviously, deleting your private key would mean that you'd have to make a new pair of private public keys. But only someone that has your private key can get into your account - and only if it's in the authorized_keys on that machine [of course, that can be copied from one place to another!]

In summary: If you feel like saving the diskspace, delete the public key. But it doesn't really matter - it's out there on the other end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a relevant answer to this question, but you can allow SSH access from specific clients (if their IPs remain fixed) by filtering them using iptables. So if a key is stolen, your firewall can help you.